# What is the largest polyculture farm?

Tags: food-crops

I'm curious if anyone has an information about the largest polyculture farms that have been able to be successful. Are planning and harvesting techniques good enough to make polyculture economically competitive at scale?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about large-scale agriculture. Please see the [help/on-topic] for more information.

Comment: @NiallC. Is there another more relevant StackExchange where I could ask this question?

Comment: I think it might fit in Sustainable Living. They have questions about poly and perma culture on occasion.